# Can't read entire table from Dyn365 F&O from canvas Power App

Tags: canvas, powerapps, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to read an entity from Dyn365 F&O using canvas Power Apps. I have followed correctly the steps from installing Finance & Operations Virtual Entity to set the TableEntity visible from advanced setting inside Power Platform admin center to connecting the TableEntity in Power Apps (see image below) but it only brings me some columns. I would like to retrive the column named "Estado de ciclo de vida actual" which is highlighted in the first picture. As you can see, I have marked all the fields in (5) inside canvas Power App but none of them reference that column.

Appreciate your help :)

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the column name and screenshots in English? The screenshots are also hard to read due to the low resolution. Could you provide them in better quality?